# Get local position of a skinned vertex

Tags: matrix, vertex, position

I have a formula for skinning, where a vertex is attached to 2 joints with some proportions:

```
B = M1*A*K1 + M2*A*K1
```

Where:

- K1 and K2 are the proportion coefficients (can be any positive numbers, but the sum is always 1.0)
- M1 - first joint transformation matrix
- M2 - second joint transformation matrix
- A - initial (local space vertex position)
- B - global space vertex position.
  With this formula I can compute vertex global position, when I know the vertex local position.

Out of this formula I get this formula to compute local space position for known global space position:

```
A = B*(M1*K1 + M2*K2)^-1
```

The formula works, but there are situations, when the result of this formula is incorrect.
For instance, if I have these input values, I get correct result:

B:

```
9.52913, 20.4455, 0.0326125
```

K1: 0.4999

K2: 0.5001

M1:

```
1         0         0         0
0         1         0         0
0         0         1         0
0         0         0         1
```

M2

```
-1         0         0   9.58201
0         1         0   18.0092
0         0        -1         0
0         0         0         1
```

A:

```
-23685.4, 11.4392, -163.06
```

But if I slightly change K1 and K2, and make them 0.5, the result is not valid.
I get the matrix, which I need to invert:

```
0         0         0         4.791
0         1         0         9.0046
0         0         0         0
0         0         0         1
```

But it is not possible, as the determinant is 0.
Could somebody help me to get A for these input parameters?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're blending between two matrices that flip the x and z axes. You can imagine as you nudge the blend weight from one toward the other, the object being transformed will shrink in the x and z axes until it's been flattened to a line parallel to y, then grow back to its original size, rotated 180 degrees about the y. At the exact 50% blend point, you have what's called a singular matrix. At that parameter value, there is no possible input that will give you your desired output. If you want to blend these as rotations rather than scales, you may want to use quaternions instead of matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried what you have in Godot like this:

```
var A = Vector3(-23685.4, 11.4392, -163.06)
var M1 = Transform(
    Basis.IDENTITY,
    Vector3.ZERO
)
var M2 = Transform(
    Basis(
        Vector3(-1, 0, 0),
        Vector3(0, 1, 0),
        Vector3(0, 0, -1)
    ),
    Vector3(9.58201, 18.0092, 0)
)
print(M1*A*0.4999 + M2*A*0.5001)
```

*Mind you, these aren't truly 4x4 matrices, but since you are not using the last row, it works.*

The result is:

```
(9.529297, 20.445601, 0.032616)
```

Which looks pretty close to what you have:

```
9.52913, 20.4455, 0.0326125
```

So I will blame this to rounding errors.

---

Let us try with this now:

```
print(M1*A*0.5 + M2*A*0.5)
```

And we get:

```
(4.791016, 20.4438, 0)
```

Please notice that the z axis is zero. Furthermore, what we got on the x axis looks very close to half the translation you have `9.58201 * 0.5 = 4.791005`.

Why did that happen?

Well, look at the matrix you got:

```
0         0         0         4.791
0         1         0         9.0046
0         0         0         0
0         0         0         1
```

The first three elements of the first row are zero. So the value the output `x` depends entirely on the last element of the first row. And the third row is all zero, which is why we get output `z` to be zero.

The last column is - of course - the factors for the fourth component of the vector. Which we are assuming to be `1`, because we are using a 3D vector. Thus, if we say that the output `x` only depends on the element on the last column, we are implying the output `x` does not depend on the input 3D vector.

Similarly we can see that the first and third columns are zero. Which tells us that the values of input `x` and `z` do not affect the result. **The input `x` and `z` could be any value, which when multiplied by zero go away (do not affect the result).**

---

Alright, now we know that the values of `x` and `z` do not depend on the input 3D vector. In other words, regardless of the input 3D vector, they are going to always have the same values. Which are `x = 4.791` and `z = 0`.

So, let us see at the value you want to get: `9.52913, 20.4455, 0.0326125`.

Nope. Just Nope. The value of `x` will always be `4.791` with this transformation. And the value of `z` will always be `0` with this transformation. Thus, there is no possible input 3D vector that will yield `9.52913, 20.4455, 0.0326125`.

**We can't solve this.**

I don't know what you are trying to solve, but my advice in general is to look for another approach. *To be clear, I don't mean another approach to invert this transformation. That can't be done. I mean another way to combine then in the first place, or another approach to solve whatever you are trying to solve that led you to this (for example, can you just store the original position?)*